# Проблемы со сборкой проекта npm run build

Tags: node.js, webpack, npm

Возникла проблема: npm выдает ошибку при попытке сборки проекта для продакшна с помощью команды npm run build. В данной теме новичок, поэтому не понимаю что не так.
Собственно код ошибки в терминале (MacOS):

```
ERROR in build.js from UglifyJs
Unexpected token: punc (() [src/App.vue:129,0][build.js:7669,6]
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 2
npm ERR! vue-kalibro@1.0.0 build: `cross-env NODE_ENV=production webpack --progress --hide-modules`
npm ERR! Exit status 2
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the vue-kalibro@1.0.0 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/username/.npm/_logs/2020-05-02T10_18_13_754Z-debug.log
```

Содержимое лога:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ '/usr/local/bin/node', '/usr/local/bin/npm', 'run', 'build' ]
2 info using npm@6.13.4
3 info using node@v12.16.1
4 verbose run-script [ 'prebuild', 'build', 'postbuild' ]
5 info lifecycle vue-kalibro@1.0.0~prebuild: vue-kalibro@1.0.0
6 info lifecycle vue-kalibro@1.0.0~build: vue-kalibro@1.0.0
7 verbose lifecycle vue-kalibro@1.0.0~build: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle vue-kalibro@1.0.0~build: PATH: /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/node-gyp-bin:/Users/username/Desktop/kalibro/node_modules/.bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/Apple/usr/bin
9 verbose lifecycle vue-kalibro@1.0.0~build: CWD: /Users/username/Desktop/kalibro
10 silly lifecycle vue-kalibro@1.0.0~build: Args: [
10 silly lifecycle   '-c',
10 silly lifecycle   'cross-env NODE_ENV=production webpack --progress --hide-modules'
10 silly lifecycle ]
11 silly lifecycle vue-kalibro@1.0.0~build: Returned: code: 2  signal: null
12 info lifecycle vue-kalibro@1.0.0~build: Failed to exec build script
13 verbose stack Error: vue-kalibro@1.0.0 build: `cross-env NODE_ENV=production webpack --progress --hide-modules`
13 verbose stack Exit status 2
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/index.js:332:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:311:20)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/lib/spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:311:20)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1021:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:286:5)
14 verbose pkgid vue-kalibro@1.0.0
15 verbose cwd /Users/username/Desktop/kalibro
16 verbose Darwin 19.3.0
17 verbose argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "run" "build"
18 verbose node v12.16.1
19 verbose npm  v6.13.4
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 2
22 error vue-kalibro@1.0.0 build: `cross-env NODE_ENV=production webpack --progress --hide-modules`
22 error Exit status 2
23 error Failed at the vue-kalibro@1.0.0 build script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 2, true ]
```

Comment: А что там такое в 129-й строке файла App.vue?

Comment: `
127 export default {
128    name: "app",
129    data() {
130        //Все значения приведенные здесь - считаются дефолтными.
131      return {
132         login: "admin",`

Comment: Извиняюсь за формат, не привык еще к этому форуму

Comment: Хм. А вот [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42375468/uglify-syntaxerror-unexpected-token-punc), часом, не Ваш случай?

Comment: Честно говоря не знаю. Я без понятия почему у меня не собирается проект. Я так понимаю, он ругается на 129 строчку в файле App.vue?  Если перейти в Build.js на строку  7669, как написано в ошибке, то там будет точно такая же строка. Понять не могу, на что там можно ругаться. К тому же, подобные строки есть и в других компонентах vue, не только в главном.

Comment: @Yaant как я понял, ошибка в той теме возникла из-за использования кода ES6, а веб-пак понимает по дефолту ES5. Ему порекомендовали установить ES6, а также плагин для we-pack'a. Затем заменить вызов ES5 на свежеустановленный ES6. я заглянул в Build.js, там по умолчанию вызывается harmony (ES6), так что проблема не в этом. Я подумал, что ошибка могла возникнуть из-за отсутствия ES6 или плагина, поэтому установил их. Ошибка прежняя.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ответов ни от кого не последовало, очень грустно. Хотя проблема как оказалось пустяковая и с ней сталкивается каждый, кто впервые работает с node.js и webpack'ом. 
Webpack не понимает код, написанный на ES6. Именно поэтому проект не собирался. Для предотвращения подобных ошибок, во VUE по умолчанию предустановлен babel - js транскомпилятор. Он при постройке проекта (npm run build) автоматически переводит ES6 в ES5 для webpack'а. Исходники он при этом не меняет. 
По какой то неизвестной мне причине, у меня попросту был отключен babel. Проблема решалась всего одной командой в терминале `vue add babel` непосредственно в папке с проектом. Прописав данную строку, проект без ошибок с первого раза нормально собрался. Эти три коротких слова мне стоили целого дня и кучу потраченных нервов. Ответ на свой вопрос я искал на англоязычных форумах, в частности на stackoverflow.